# create javascript date array from php date array and see if a specific value matches

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have a PHP array of DateTime objects like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 2019-04-16 [1] => 2019-04-17 [2] => 2019-04-18 [3] => 2019-04-19 )
```

I hold this array in a PHP variable `$oldArraytep`. At runtime i build a calendar and i want to highlight specific dates that are in the `$oldArraytep` array.

To do this i was planning on:

1. converting the php array to javascript array
2. at run time check if there is a specific `myJavascriptArray.includes(date("Y-m-d", (timeinmilli/1000)));`

Where i am completely lost is on how to convert a php array of DateTime into an javascript array of `date`

Comment: What i am looking for help is converting a php date array to javascript date array. I am not having issues with passing variables around.

Comment: Loop through javascript array and change string dates to date objects